# Fortnite files structure - how to find quest description?

Tags: unreal-4, data-structure, unreal-5, file

Fortnite files can be discovered with FModel. This is unreal engine project.

I would like to understand how it works.
For ex., I found the following record at AssetRegistry.json:

```
{
  "ObjectPath": "/BattlePassS24/Items/QuestItems/PartyQuests/quest_s24_DailyPunchcard_Complete1.quest_s24_DailyPunchcard_Complete1",
  "PackageName": "/BattlePassS24/Items/QuestItems/PartyQuests/quest_s24_DailyPunchcard_Complete1",
  "PackagePath": "/BattlePassS24/Items/QuestItems/PartyQuests",
  "AssetName": "quest_s24_DailyPunchcard_Complete1",
  "AssetClass": "AthenaDailyQuestDefinition",
  "TagsAndValues": {
    "bNeverPersisted": "False",
    "DisplayName": "NSLOCTEXT(\"[11EF0A9E119F4D09A17AB91694C84970]\", \"C9C045254C186D23D570B0BBBDF258C9\", \"Complete 1 Daily Quest\")",
    "ItemType": "Quest",
    "PrimaryAssetName": "quest_s24_DailyPunchcard_Complete1",
    "PrimaryAssetType": "Quest"
  },
  "ChunkIDs": [
    10
  ],
  "PackageFlags": 2147754496
},
```

How can I find the translated description, picture, quest location and reward?